# Why does the order of borrowing matter in rust?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn say_hello(s: &str) {
    println!("Hello {}", s);
}
```

Why does this work

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut name = String::from("Charlie");
    let x = &mut name;
    say_hello(x);
    name.push_str(" Brown");
}
```

but this doesn't?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut name = String::from("Charlie");
    let x = &mut name;
    name.push_str(" Brown");
    say_hello(x);
}
```

all I did was switch the order of the two functions but it seems like `x` has mutably borrowed name and push_str has also mutably borrowed name in both situations, so why does the first example compile?

If I take out the call to `say_hello()` why does the order of the two not matter even though there are still two mutable borrows?

Edit:
Is this similar?

```rust
fn change_string(s: &mut String) { // s is mutably borrowed but isn't used yet
    println!("{}", s.is_empty()); // so the scopes don't overlap even though is_empty is making an immutable borrow?
    s.push_str(" Brown");
}
```

Comment: regarding your edit: the mutable reference (`s`) can be re-borrowed into an immutable reference (`self` for `is_empty()`), the mutable reference can't be used while the immutable reference exits but since it is only lives during the `s.is_empty()` expression, its not an issue to use `s` afterwards.

Answer (score 10):

One of Rust's borrowing rules is that [mutable references are exclusive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references). Meaning, while `x` is alive, `name` cannot be used.

So, why does the first example compile even if `x` is still in scope? Because Rust also has [non-lexical lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html) meaning `x` stops "living" after its last use.

```
fn main() {
    let mut name = String::from("Charlie");
    let x = &mut name;
    say_hello(x);            // "x"s lifetime ends here, releasing the exclusive borrow
    name.push_str(" Brown"); // "name" can be used again
}
```

Comment: Mentioning NLL (non-lexical lifetime) is important because it is _the_ reason the first example compiles (in Rust 2018). In Rust 2015 which doesn't support NLL, neither examples compile.

Answer (score 5):

Because in your first case, the two **mutable borrow** scopes don't overlap and you have only one borrow at any given point of time; but in your second case, they overlap, which means you have multiple **mutable borrows** at the certain point of time, which is not allowed:

First case:

```
fn main() {
    let mut name = String::from("Charlie");
    let x = &mut name;
    say_hello(x);             // the mutable borrow ends here
    name.push_str(" Brown");  // a new mutable borrow
}
```

Second case:

```
fn main() {
    let mut name = String::from("Charlie");
    let x = &mut name;
    name.push_str(" Brown");  // the first mutable borrow is still 
                      // alive, you have two mutable borrows here
    say_hello(x);       // the first mutable borrow ends here
}
```

Comment: I think you should also specify that it's a _mutable_ borrow and keeping alive two of them is not allowed in rust

Comment: Wow! Never knew borrow lives until the last usage of a variable, not until the end of scope

Comment: @AlexLarionov Yeah, it's pretty easy to ignore but very neat once you figure it out, IMO.

Comment: Is my function in the edit similar in that as long as the scopes don't overlap, it is okay to make a mutable borrow and an immutable borrow or make two mutable borrows or is it different?

Comment: @Rafael In your edited function, you are not borrowing anything but using the same reference. But I don't have a great explanation for that. You might get a better answer if you ask a different question. (actually check kmdreko's comment)