# Return reference wrapped in struct that requires lifetime parameters

Tags: rust, lifetime

How can I return a reference wrapped in a struct and what lifetime annotation is required? I am having a tough time formulating my exact question, but the following example illustrates what I am trying to do. I have a struct `C` that contains a reference to a struct `B` that requires lifetime parameters. I want a function on `C` that returns the reference to `B` wrapped in another struct `Borrower` that functions as an interface.

When compiling this I get an error when returning `Borrower`: 'cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'b` due to conflicting requirements'. How can I resolve this issue? What lifetime parameters can I enter? I feel like both `'a` and `'b` are not the right lifetimes.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0aaae131122a03e7c3311a6c678f94f)

```rust
struct C<'a, 'b> {
    ref2: &'a mut B<'b>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> C<'a, 'b> {
    fn get_borrower(&mut self) -> Borrower {
        Borrower { ref3: self.ref2 }
    }
}

struct Borrower<'a, 'b> {
    ref3: &'a mut B<'b>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Borrower<'a, 'b> {
    fn print_and_add(&mut self) {
        println!("ref is {}", self.ref3.ref1.i);
        self.ref3.ref1.i += 1;
    }
}

struct B<'a> {
    ref1: &'a mut A,
}

struct A {
    i: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A { i: 10 };
    let mut b = B { ref1: &mut a };
    let mut c = C { ref2: &mut b };

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let mut borrower = c.get_borrower();
        borrower.print_and_add();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is specifically in this method:

```
impl<'a, 'b> C<'a, 'b> {
    fn get_borrower(&mut self) -> Borrower {
        Borrower { ref3: self.ref2 }
    }
}
```

We need to help the compiler understand which lifetime parameters are expected in the returned `Borrower`, because the inferred lifetimes here will be incorrect: The lifetime elision `Borrower` can be expanded to `Borrower<'_, '_>` where the anonymous lifetimes are both the lifetime of `&mut self`; If we call it `'s`, the equivalent signature would be:

```
    fn get_borrower<'s>(&'s mut self) -> Borrower<'s, 's> {
```

This is clearly not right, because we know that the second lifetime is expected to be `'b`, as directly described by field `ref2` of type `B<'b>`. With the following signature (and after fixing unrelated errors), [the code compiles successfully](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8cfc62aa37acd336023f5a7b52d81a0):

```rust
    fn get_borrower(&mut self) -> Borrower<'_, 'b> {
```

The fun part is in the first parameter. One could be inclined to assume that we want it to be `'a` instead of `'s`, but that would still lead to conflicting lifetimes:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         Borrower { ref3: self.ref2 }
  |         ^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'s` as defined on the method body at 6:21...
 --> src/main.rs:6:21
  |
6 |     fn get_borrower<'s>(&'s mut self) -> Borrower<'a, 'b> {
  |                     ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:7:26
  |
7 |         Borrower { ref3: self.ref2 }
  |                          ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 5:6...
 --> src/main.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<'a, 'b> C<'a, 'b> {
  |      ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         Borrower { ref3: self.ref2 }
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: expected `Borrower<'a, 'b>`
             found `Borrower<'_, '_>`
```

This is because we are retrieving `ref2` behind a *mutable* reference to self, and that one has its own lifetime. We cannot just move it out of `self` by force to fulfill the lifetime `'a`, nor can we pass a `&'s mut &'a mut B<'b>` instead. Therefore, returning a `Borrower<'s, 'b>` is the right thing to do: as it is implicit that `'a: 's` (`'a` outlives `'s`), the covariance in this lifetime will enable this method to narrow the mutable reference `&'a mut B<'b>` into its subtype `&'s mut B<'b>`.

```
 ---------- 
| 'a       |
| ------   |
|| 's   | ---> Borrower<'s, 'b>
||      |  |
| ------   |
 ----------
```

See also:

- [mutably borrow fields from a mutably borrowed struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68797851)
- [How can this instance seemingly outlive its own parameter lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637911)